# How to draw stroke within boundaries on a bitmap image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, bitmap, core-image

[image]

I’m creating a drawing app similar to pigment on iOS.
I would like to know if there are any ideas on how to implement the drawing strokes within the limited boundaries like in the example image

I think the best approach I’ve tried is to create a clipped Bézier path and constrain drawing into that ,  but I’m stuck on how to generate a Bézier path from the white area I’ve selected

Can anyone explain how to do that or provide an alternative approach ?